# Retrieve text from jQuery to HTML after clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learner for HTML and jQuery. Trying to retrieve the text from jquery to html

JQuery: To return textbox value after clicking button.

```
$('#value').click(function() {
    var value = $("#test").val();
    return value;
    });
```

HTML: Typing the text and clicking on button.

```
<input type="text" id= "test" title="details/>
<input type ="button" id="value" value ="Detail" /> 
<!-- any suggestions how to get the stored value from jquery to html --!>
```

Is there a way to return the text value from jquery to HTML code so that i can able to some operations after clicking on submit button.

Can you please provide any suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to do? .val() will give you the value, do you want to display it on the page?

Comment: `return` here doesn't do what you think it does!

Comment: You can't process information with HTML, so really there is no point in "returning" to HTML: what is it you would like to accomplish in the long run?

Comment: Instead of returning the value, may be call a user defined function and pass the `value` as a param. Then, you can do whatever you want to, within the function.

Comment: Have to do operation after clicking on submit button and need to create hyperlink after returning the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is your trying to do? If i'm understanding correctly basically; you've landed on a page (page1) on page 1 there an element with a value(hidden or not) that when a button is clicked it lands into an empty text box? For example,

```
<p>Is your name <span id="name">John</span>?</p>
<br/>
<button id="yes_get_name" value="submit">Yes</button>

<input type="text" id="insert_tname" name="name" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Trigger function when Button Clicked
   $( "#yes_get_name" ).click(function() {
   // Assigne Name as a variable
   var name;
   // Assign Value of Name as text of span id="Name"
   var name = $('#name').text()
   // Insert names value into input
   $("#insert_tname").val(name);
   });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps. Other than this i might be misunderstanding the question.
Here's a [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/csagherian/1bphjurm/) on the roof to test.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can use following to write back into textbox:

```
$("#test").val("something");
```

Comment: how does this have any bearing on what was asked?